# Jersey 2.X Rest project with maven without web.xml Eclipse Photon

Tags: tomcat8, jersey-2.0, eclipse-photon

I am trying to implement a simple Jersey project using Jersey 2.16, and referring Javabrain Kaushik's tutorial of advanced JaxRs. Here the application invocation will be without web.xml but via @ApplicationPath annotation of javax. I am getting 404 while running the application

MyApp.java

```
package org.javabrains.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class MyApp extends Application {

}
```

MyResource.java

```
package org.javabrains.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("test")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testMethod() {
        return "It works!";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.javabrains</groupId>
  <artifactId>advanced-jaxrs-01</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>advanced-jaxrs-01 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <finalName>advanced-jaxrs-01</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


</project>
```

I have tried to refer to old stackoverflow questions, but no luck.
I am running it in tomcat 8 and application url localhost:8082/advanced-jaxrs-01/webapi/test

Below is my project facet details[image]